# Working JSOM and Angular together for App Part

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app, jsom, angularjs, app-part

I currently have an app part built with REST and Angular. The issue I am having is that I'm getting Page Not Found errors from users with slower connections. I was told that JSOM would be considerably faster but I can't seem to connect it with Angular.

This is what I currently have:

```
(function (angular) {
var BlogTitle = BlogURL;
    angular.module('blogPart', ['ngSanitize'])
      .controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope, $timeout) {
          BackgroundColor = "{'background-color':'" + BackgroundColor + "'}";
          $scope.BackgroundColor = BackgroundColor;
          $scope.PostLimit = PostLimit;
          var today = new Date();
          var getPostQuantity = PostLimit + 7;

          jQuery.ajax({
              url: BlogTitle + "/_api/web/lists/getbyTitle('Posts')/items?" +
                  "$select=ID,Title,Body,Author/Id,Author/Title,NumComments/Id,LikesCount,LikedBy/Name,PublishedDate&$orderby=PublishedDate desc" +
                  "&$expand=Author,NumComments,LikedBy" +
                  "&$filter=PublishedDate le datetime'" + today.toISOString() + "'" +
                  "&$top=" + getPostQuantity,
              type: "GET",
              headers: {
                  "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
              },
              success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                  //fill model
                  var postResults = data.d.results;
                  var items = [];
                  for (var i = 0; i < postResults.length; i++) {
                      var item = {
                          id: postResults[i].ID,
                          title: postResults[i].Title,
                          numComments: postResults[i].NumComments.Id,
                          commentsUrl: BlogURL + "/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=" + postResults[i].ID + "#comments",
                          userUrl: hostUrl + "/_layouts/15/userdisp.aspx?ID=" + postResults[i].Author.Id,
                          numLikes: likes,
                          liked: isliked
                      };
                      items.push(item);
                  }
                  //update ui
                  $scope.$apply(function () {
                      $scope.items = items;
                  });
                  Communica.Part.init();
              },
              error: function (jqXHR, status, message) {
                  $scope.$apply(function () {
                      $scope.error = "Error: " + message;
                  });
              }
          });
      }]);
(window.angular);
```

I have this for JSOM but and I can get the data but how do I connect it with Angular? I tried starting it like I did with REST and that does not work.

```
function execCrossDomainRequest() {
var context;
var factory;
var appContextSite;
var mylist;
context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostUrl);
this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
mylist = this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('Posts');
var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
var collListItem = mylist.getItems(camlQuery);
context.load(mylist);
context.load(collListItem);
context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this, successHandler),
     Function.createDelegate(this, errorHandler)
);

function successHandler() {
    var listItemInfo = '';
    var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
    var listTitle = mylist.get_title();
    while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
        listItemInfo += "<li style='height: 20px;'>" + oListItem.get_item('Title') + "</li>";
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = '<h1>' + mylist.get_title() + '</h1><br />';
        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += listItemInfo.toString();
    }
}
function errorHandler() {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
}
```

Comment: the 404 is not likely due to your API choice, and in any case I doubt the notion that JSOM is faster. I suspect the opposite is true.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery.ajax inside angular? see my article about sharepoint and angularjs http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1002526/SharePoint-and-Angularjs

Comment: You are only giving is part of the code. What's in the HTML? There is no loop for ``postResults`` and in the second block you are creating a HTML structure which should be done in the Angular View with an ``ng-repeat`` loop (like I presume you do with ``items`` in the first block)

Comment: the use of $scope.apply should also not be necessary, it is only required when other code touches the DOM. ``$scope.items=items`` (or just directly built that ``$scope.items`` in a loop is enough

Comment: How do I add HTML without it trying to render?

Comment: @AtishDipongkor because I'm new to this and it works...

Comment: @DannyEngelman I missed the for loop in my copy & paste, added now. That code works, not the question. It is just an example. I was hoping for some help with creating a JSOM Angular project or a reason why 404 is thrown for the slower users.

Answer (score 0):

In the script below assumes you are hard coding the SP.js file into the page/masterpage instead of using the on demand syntax (SP.SOD)

Try this
first create a factory and make sure it is has the $q capability

```
 .factory('myRESTFactory',factory($q){return function(){
 var deferred=$q.defer();
 var context; 
 var factory;
 var appContextSite;
 var mylist;
 context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);     
 factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
 context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
 appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostUrl);
 this.web = appContextSite.get_web();
 mylist =this.web.get_lists().getByTitle('Posts');
 var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
 camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
 var collListItem=mylist.getItems(camlQuery);
 context.load(mylist);
 context.load(collListItem);
 context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this, function(){
           var listItemInfo = '';
           var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();
           var listTitle = mylist.get_title();
           var listObject=[]
           while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
              var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
              listObject.push(oListItem.get_properties())
           };
           deferred.resolve(listObject)
           }),
     Function.createDelegate(this,function(sender,args){
       deferred.reject(args.get_message())
     }));
```

return deferred.promise();
     }})

Then call the function in this way in the angular controller after adding your dependancy to "myRESTFactory"

```
$scope.myListItems=myRESTFactory()
                     .then(function(successObj){
                             console.log(successObj)
                           },
                           function(errorObj){
                             console.log(errorObj)
                           })
```

hope this helps

SECOND NOTE:

Instead of  using AJAX in the controller, use .service or .factory to make a $http() async call. it removes the clutter from your controller and is more Angular-esque

a good format for this is

```
 .service('myService',function($http,$q){
    return {
      myFunction:function(){
            var deferred=$q.defer();
            var xreq={} //some object with headers - incompletecode
            $http(xreq).success(function(obj){deferred.resolve(obj)})
                       .fail(function(err){deferred.reject(err)})
           return deferred.promise();
      }
    }
 })
```